# Locking with USB drive

Tags: usb, security, lock-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock and Unlock from USB disk (pendrive)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28836/lock-and-unlock-from-usb-disk-pendrive)

When i use Windows, there is a program I use called **[Predator](http://www.predator-usb.com/predator/en/index.php)** that locks my PC when I remove a certain USB flash drive. It then unlocks the computer when I reinsert it.

Is there any program like this for Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you explain what the program does?

Comment: @January You **don't know** about [Predator](http://www.predator-usb.com/predator/en/index.php)? :O

Comment: @SirCharlo I do know about [this Predator](http://cotocrew.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/predator.jpg) only; since I hardly ever used Windows, I can hardly know every weird little program for Windows.

Comment: @January http://www.predator-usb.com/predator/en/index.php

Comment: @January It ain't weird. It's awesome :)

Comment: GUTS GUYS GUYS . i dont want comments about how much predator is good ?

Comment: Why would anyone use anything like that? Escapes my comprehension.

Comment: if anyone is lazy to write password so he'll use it :D

Comment: @January Meh.. Lock and unlock quickly without entering a password.

Comment: The program you're looking for should be easy to implement if it doesn't exist for Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh, typing deficiency, I get it (it would take me much more time to fumble with a USB stick, dig it out from my trousers pocket, putting it the right way in the USB slot... while typing the password is as good as instant)

Comment: those are thousands linux guys . and i think only i didnt found it @aking1012

Comment: Full disk encryption with a passphrase stored on a USB stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of any program but you can create a simple script that can do that like in this example:

http://www.techienote.com/2011/03/lock-unlock-ubuntu-desktop-using-usb-drive.html

Comment: how i can find my USB ID ?

Comment: It's explained on that site in terminal "...run lsusb and locate your USB Device..."

Comment: is there any recovery when i lost my drive?

Comment: @EnesKuray Check out my last comment, under your question.

Comment: @EnesKuray you can always enter your password to login to desktop

Comment: how can i use 2 device ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, a module called PAM (Pluggable Authentication module) can be customized to achieve your need. A beautiful article is available on [**linuxconfig**](http://linuxconfig.org/linux-authentication-login-with-usb-device) describing this in detail.

The steps are:

1. Install PAM

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install pamusb-tools libpam-usb
   ```
2. Add USB device to PAM config

   ```
   $ sudo pamusb-conf --add-device <my-usb-stick>
   ```
3. Select your volume and "**Y**" to save
4. Define user for PAM auth

   ```
   $ sudo pamusb-conf --add-user <ubuntu-user>
   ```
5. Select and "**Y**" to save
6. Configure PAM

   ```
   $ sudo gedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth
   ```
7. Add the line below and save

   ```
   auth    sufficient      pam_usb.so
   ```
8. Test the PAM auth

   ```
   $ su ubuntu-user
   ```
9. Lock when disconnected

   ```
   $ sudo gedit /etc/pamusb.conf
   ```
10. Modify the block "user" block to look like:

    ```
    <user id="ubuntu-user"> 
          <device> 
                  my-usb-stick 
          </device> 
          <agent event="lock">gnome-screensaver-command -l</agent> 
          <agent event="unlock">gnome-screensaver-command -d</agent> 
     </user>*
    ```

[**cuttlefish**](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/cuttlefish-set-actions-reactions-automate-ubuntu/) could be one solution to do it as @maythux suggested. I really can't comment on its capabilities, I prefer to stay away from 3rd party apps as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **cuttlefish**

It does what you need plus more advanced options see this [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/cuttlefish-set-actions-reactions-automate-ubuntu/) to learn about